# Angular Jasmine unable to test onInit method using Observable

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, observable

I am trying to test ngOnInit of a Component where I subscribe to an Observable.
Here is the method to test:

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.configService.configLoadedEvent$.subscribe(() => { // waiting for loading configuration
      console.log('Configuration has been loaded');
      this.initExternalServices();
    });
  }
```

Here is the spec file:

```
    describe('TestComponent', () => {
  const mockedConfigurationService = jasmine.createSpyObj('ConfigurationService', ['getConfig']);
  
  let testComponent = new TestComponent(mockedConfigurationService);

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(testComponent).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should init', () => {
    testComponent.ngOnInit();
    mockedConfigurationService.configLoadedEvent$ = new Subject().next(true);

    // External system ok
    mockedExternalSystemsService.isSystemStatusOk.and.returnValue(of(Promise.resolve()));

    expect(testComponent.workflowService.isState(State.READY)).toBeTrue();
  });
```

In the console, I don't see "Configuration has been loaded". There are two issues there. One is how to simulate a ***next*** on a mocked Service? The other is: how we can make Jasmine wait for an Observable before that ***expect*** is called? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your test is synchronous, you will need to use `fakeAsync()`

Comment: Ok thanks. I used waitForAsync and it seemed to work much better!

Answer (score 0):

***| One is how to simulate a next on a mocked Service?***

I think you have an issue of late subscribing.

Try the following changes:

```
// Declare a new subject and associate it the observalbe as the third property
// in the jasmine.createSpyObj. The third object property are instance variables
// for the mock.
const mockConfigLoadedEventSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
const mockedConfigurationService = jasmine.createSpyObj('ConfigurationService', ['getConfig'], { configLoadedEvent: mockConfigLoadedEventSubject.asObservabe() });
...

it('should init', () => {
    testComponent.ngOnInit();
    // Get rid of this line, not needed anymore.
    // mockedConfigurationService.configLoadedEvent$ = new Subject().next(true);

    // External system ok
    mockedExternalSystemsService.isSystemStatusOk.and.returnValue(of(Promise.resolve()));

    expect(testComponent.workflowService.isState(State.READY)).toBeTrue();
  });
```

***| how we can make Jasmine wait for an Observable before that expect is called?***

You can do this using `fakeAsync/tick` although most times I have noticed it is not needed.

```
// Wrap callback with fakeAsync
it('should init', fakeAsync(() => {
    testComponent.ngOnInit();
    
    // External system ok
    mockedExternalSystemsService.isSystemStatusOk.and.returnValue(of(Promise.resolve()));
    // Call tick to make sure all asynchronous tasks have completed
    // before going to expect.
    tick();
    expect(testComponent.workflowService.isState(State.READY)).toBeTrue();
  }));
```